# How to access Django DB and ORM outside of Django

Tags: python, django, orm

So in my spare time, I've been developing a piece of network monitoring software that essentially can be installed on a bunch of clients, and the clients report data back to the server(RAM/CPU/Storage/Network usage, and the like). For the administrative console as well as reporting, I've decided to use Django, which has been a learning experience in itself.

The `Client`s report to the `Server` asynchronously, with whatever data they happen to have(As of right now, it's just received and dumped, not stored in a DB). I need to access this data in Django. I have already created the models to match my needs. However, I don't know how to go about getting the actual data into the django DB safely.

What is the way to go about doing this?  I thought of a few options, but they all had some drawbacks:

1. Give the Django app a reference to the `Server`, and just start a thread that continuously checks for new data and writes it to the DB.
2. Have the `Server` access the Django DB directly, and write it's data there.

The problem with `1` is that im even more tightly coupling the server with the django app, but the upside is that I can use the ORM to write the data nicely.

The problem with `2` is that I can't use the ORM to write data, and I'm not sure if it could cause blocking on the DB in some cases.

Is there some obvious good option I'm missing? I'm sorry if this question is vague. I'm very new to Django, and I don't want to write myself into a corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a message bus (see [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)).

Each time your client needs to record something, it will submit a message on a queue. On your django side, you have a broker that is managing workers.

The broker monitors the queue for a message, fires up the worker to process the message, and then puts the worker back to sleep.

The worker updates the database.

This way you don't have to deal with continuous threads (which are a cause of many headaches) and your architecture can easily expand to handle multiple clients by simply adding to the message processing pipeline.

Comment: I should add more information: I'm using Pyro4 to handle communications from the `client`s to the `server` application, and I need to get the data from my `server` application, to the actual django application.  The `server` just has a local dict of all incoming data. Is celery still viable here? I suppose it would just check if the `server`'s dictionary content had changed?

Answer (score 1):

I chose option `1` when I set up my environment, which does much of the same stuff.

I have a JSON interface that's used to pass data back to the server.  Since I'm on a well-protected VLAN, this works great.  The biggest benefit, like you say, is the Django ORM.  A simple address call with proper data is all that's needed.  I also think this is the simplest method.

The "blocking on the DB" issue *should* be non-existent.  I suppose that it would depend on the DB backend, but really, that's one of the benefits of a DB.  For example, a single-threaded file-based sqlite instance may not work.

I keep things in Django as much as I can.  This could also help with DB security/integrity, since it's only ever accessed in one place.  If your client accesses the DB directly, you'll need to *ship* username/password with the `Client`.

My recommendation is to go with `1`.  It will make your life easier, with fewer lines of code.  Besides, as long as you code `Client` properly, it should be easy to modify DB access later on down the road.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you, I should make a route in django that handles post requests from the `Server` with all of my data in it, and whenever it receives data, just use the ORM to write it to the db?

Comment: Right.  That's what I did.  I'm only sending small bits of data, so JSON works fine.  I don't even need POST.  Your case may be different.  You would handle all of the *incoming* data in your view.  Nice and simple.